# read variable names from csv file with ansible and substitute with values

Tags: python, csv, ansible, lookup

I am trying to create an environment specific configuration file consisting of key = value pairs that are read from a csv file.
The csv file contains configuration settings for many environments and I need to generate a configuration file for each environment depending on inventory used by playbook.

The CSV file settings.csv

```
Key|siteA-test|siteA-prod|siteB-test|siteB-prod|Comment
param1|true|true|false|false|Comment for param1
param2|http://test|http://prod|||Comment for param2
param3|ansible_variable_A_test|ansible_variable_A_prod|ansible_variable_B_test|ansible_variable_B_prod|Variable must be taken from secret vault
param4|ansible_variable_C_test|ansible_variable_C_prod|ansible_variable_D_test| ansible_variable_D_prod|Another variable from variable file
```

Intended file for siteA-test would look like:

```
param1=true # Comment for param1
param2=http://test # Comment for param2
param3=secret_value_from_vault # Variable must be taken from secret vault 
param4=1984 # Another variable from variable file
```

I will write this out to a file using lineinfile module.

So far I have (somewhat ugly) figured out how to get values for specific environments, by creating a dictionary of keys first and then iterating over that dict.
I don't like that I have to read CSV file twice, but this works.

```
- hosts: hostgroupA
  tasks:
  - name: Read CSV file and return a dictionary
    community.general.read_csv:
      path: settings.csv
      delimiter: '|'
      key: Key
      strict: yes
    register: config
    delegate_to: localhost

  - ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "Key {{ lookup('csvfile', '{{item.key}} file=settings.csv col=1 delimiter=|') }}, value: {{ lookup('csvfile', '{{item.key}} file=settings.csv col=2 delimiter=|')}} "
    loop: "{{ config.dict| dict2items }}"
    delegate_to: localhost
```

The problem is that I don't know if it is possible to replace variable names for param3 and param4 with real values from vaults or other variable files.

Comment: Frankly, it seems you're trying to get Ansible to do things it's not really good at.  You could have a play calling the `shell` module to parse the file with `sed`, `awk`, `cut`, `tr`, or other tools and write the vars file in yaml format, then have another play to load that newly created file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lookup` plugin `vars`. See `ansible-doc -t lookup vars`. For example, given simplified inventory. (Encrypt test*_var if you want to. The best option might be to put the variables into encrypted files stored in host_vars).

```yaml
shall> cat hosts
testA testA_var="A"
testB testB_var="B"
```

and the simplified CSV file settings.csv, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat settings.csv
Key|testA|testB|Comment
param1|true|false|Comment for param1
param2|testA_var|testB_var|Var from vault
```

The playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - read_csv:
      path: settings.csv
      delimiter: '|'
      key: Key
      strict: yes
    register: config
    delegate_to: localhost
    run_once: true

  - debug:
      msg: "param1: {{ _p1 }}, param2: {{ _p2 }}"
    vars:
      _p1: "{{ config.dict.param1[inventory_hostname] }}"
      _p2: "{{ lookup('vars', config.dict.param2[inventory_hostname]) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [testB] => 
  msg: 'param1: false, param2: B'
ok: [testA] => 
  msg: 'param1: true, param2: A'
```

---

If you want to iterate the hosts, e.g.

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item }} param1: {{ _p1 }}, param2: {{ _p2 }}"
    loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
    vars:
      _p1: "{{ config.dict.param1[item] }}"
      _varname: "{{ config.dict.param2[item] }}"
      _p2: "{{ hostvars[item][_varname] }}"
    run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: 'testA param1: true, param2: A'
  msg: 'testB param1: false, param2: B'
```

Comment: Yes, this is getting me much closer to what I wanted to achieve! Thanks, much appreciated!